# Insert a word in the first line of the file

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

Input:

```
firstline
secondline
thirdline
```

...some magic happens here... :)

Output:

```
insertedtextfirstline
secondline
thirdline
```

**Question**: How can I insert the *insertedtext* to the start of the first line in a file?

Comment: Do you have to enter only at the first line of the file, or this first line at different sections of the file, for example, paragraphs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i '1s/^/insertedtext/' file
```

This replaces the beginning of the first line with the inserted text. `-i` replaces the text in `file` rather than sending the modified text to the standard output.

Answer (score 7):

If portability across unices is a concern, use `ed`:

```
ed file <<END
1s/^/insertedtext/
w
q
END
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `ed(1)`. :)

Answer (score 5):

POSIX one:

```
$ { printf %s insertedtext; cat <./input_file; } >/tmp/output_file
$ mv -- /tmp/output_file ./input_file
```

Comment: This is the fastest method (compared to `sed`, `ed` or `ex`).

Answer (score 4):

In perl

```
perl -pi -e 's/^/insertedtext/ if $.==1' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variation - not more or less correct, just a matter of taste:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "insertedtext"};{print $0}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU `sed` will do.

```
sed -i '1s/\(.*\)/insertedtext\1/'
```

However, note that appending at the beginning of the file requires rewriting of its whole content. In case of small files it is not a problem, but if the file in question has several dozens of gigabytes, then it might become a tricky task to do it efficiently.

In such cases you usually want to make some dirty tricks, like ensuring that the replacement text has exactly the same length as the original one, and just modify the selected bytes in-place.

Comment: gorkypl has a point. If you have a large document with multiple first line situations, you might to invest in a proper code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<<IN head -n-1 >textfile
insertedtext$(
cat   <textfile
printf \\n.)
IN
```

In those shells which handle heredocuments with tempfiles *(to include `bash` and `zsh` but not `dash`, `busybox`, or `yash`)* the above command will safely overwrite the whole of *`textfile`* with itself and include the prepended string. The trailing `\n.` is added to preserve any trailing blanklines in *`textfile`* - which would otherwise be stripped by the command substitution.

Comment: This one removed all trailing newlines of `infile`.

Comment: @cuonglm - good point.